# Multiple URL for single webapp in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish-3

I am using GlassFish v3 with struts2 
I am trying to use multiple URL for single webapp 
i.e.

www.abc.com,
www.def.com

Is it possible in glassfish ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

The domain name should be irrelevant to your application. It should answer to every request made to the correct IP and port.

Comment: How can I resovle mutliple domains such as www.xyz.com and www.abc.com to single IP address and port like 192.168.4.4:8080. I am hosting my web application on 192.168.4.4:8080.

Comment: For your local network (like 192.168.*.*) you can simply add the host name to your `hosts` file. Google for "hosts file" and the name of your os for a howto.